# Javascript Element scrollTo compatibility difference between caniuse and mozilla

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, mozilla, scrollto, caniuse

I am looking for browser support information of `Element.scrollTo` method.
However, there is difference in results from caniuse and mozilla for the latest safari(iOS) and Edge.

From [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo#Browser_Compatibility), it says these browsers do not support this method. But [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=element-scroll-methods) says they do support.

[image: mozilla]

[image: caniuse]

When I tested with iPhone X, iOS 13.3.1, the method worked perfectly, which means that mozilla is wrong.

So far, I have trusted mozilla for the compatibility check purpose because this website is more descriptive on (other) technical information (thus, more reliable?).

**In a long term**, should I rely on caniuse, rather than mozilla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply from Alexis @ caniuse team

> In this case the information at
>   https://caniuse.com/#feat=element-scroll-methods is correct regarding
>   iOS support. I've submitted feedback on the MDN support table. For
>   future reference you can do so too using the "What are we missing"
>   button at
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo#Browser_Compatibility

Answer (score 1):

If you search specific `scrollTo` keyword(not just scroll) on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollto), you will get almost identicle results as Mozilla.

But interesting fact is, data on caniuse, is powered by Mozilla's **MDN browser-compat-data**(refer **Notes** tab at the bottom on caniuse) and going forward, this collaboration with MDN is going to improve. So in a long term, referring to either caniuse or mozilla, is going to be the same. But I personally prefer MDN because of its clutter-free simple portal with additional(essential) details.

Here is an [article about caniuse-MDN collaboration](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/09/caniuse-and-mdn-compat-data-collaboration/).

Comment: thank you. your caniuse link is what I need. However, I am confused by the caniuse page provided in my question. it might be a mistake (bug) of caniuse.

Comment: I have sent feedback to caniuse. Now waiting for their reply